# How to define a new Function and mixin a Trait

Tags: scala

I would define a new `Function1` and mix-in a trait, to implement a kind of *lightweight* stackable trait pattern.

I try that but it doesn't compile

```
scala> trait Filtering extends (String => Unit) { abstract override def apply(s: String) { if (s.startsWith("foo")) super.apply(s) }}
defined trait Filtering

scala> val f = new Function1[String, Unit] {def apply(s: String) = println(s)} with Filtering
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
       val f = new Function1[String, Unit] {def apply(s: String) = println(s)} with Filtering
```

And I would like to avoid creating a class :

```
class Default extends (String => Unit) {
  def apply(s : String) = println(s)
}

val f = new Default with Filtering
```

Comment: `with Filtering` should come before the implementation. `new Function1[String, Unit] with Filtering { ... }`

Comment: ^ the comment is right, but still will not solve the issue. Pretty much what you have at the end of your Q (defining `class Default`) is the right way to do it.

Comment: @PeterNeyens it doesn't compile : error: overriding method apply in trait Filtering of type (s: String)Unit;
 method apply needs `override' modifier

Comment: @YannMoisan Like @marios commented, you will still need to implement the `apply` method in a class, like your `Default`. If you are looking at the [stackable trait pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) you will see the `BasicIntQueue` has implemented the methods.

Comment: so using an anonymous class is not possible in that case ?